# Iphone fetching data from core data and displaying in table

Tags: iphone, core-data, uitableview

Error: "reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name "

I have created a new project using the tabbed application. I created multiple tabs and then added core data functions in my delegate.h files as below.

```
    @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

    - (void)saveContext;
     - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
```

Now I changed the delegate.m file as below

```
    @synthesize window = _window;
    @synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
    @synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
    @synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Application lifecycle

    - (void)saveContext
    {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
     if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
           // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
           // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
              } 
           }
         }

         - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
             {
             // Override point for customization after application launch.

              return YES;
               }

        - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
           {

            }

      - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
           {

            }

      - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
         {

          }

      - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
         {
         }

      - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
         {

         [self saveContext];

           }



  #pragma mark - Core Data stack


     - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
        {
          if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
              return __managedObjectContext;
               }

           NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
           if (coordinator != nil) {
               __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
               [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
                 }
              return __managedObjectContext;
                 }


       - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
           {
            if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
                  return __managedObjectModel;
                    }
              NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myapp" withExtension:@"momd"];
             __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
               return __managedObjectModel;
                 }

      - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
          {
           if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
              return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
              }

            NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myapp.sqlite"];

            NSError *error = nil;
            __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
            if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

           NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
             }    

        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

    #pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

      - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
       {
         return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory            inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
         }

       @end
```

I have a view controller where I am adding the data and I am able to fetch the data as well but when I am doing the same to fetch the data from the table I am getting an error where it is not able to find the coredata table. 
my myappTableViewController.h file is as follows:

```
          #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
          #import "myappAppDelegate.h"

          @interface myappTableViewController : UITableViewController 


          @property(nonatomic,retain)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
          @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *arr;

         -(void)getData;

           @end
```

In myappTableViewController.m file I added the following code:

```
   -(void)getData{

             NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Data" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

             NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

             [request setFetchBatchSize:20];

             [request setEntity:entity];

             NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

            NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];

           [request setSortDescriptors:newArray];

           NSError *error;

           NSMutableArray *results = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

           [self setArr:results];

           [self.tableView reloadData];


           }
```

and I am calling   [self getData]; in ViewDidLoad. and synthesizing

```
          @synthesize managedObjectContext,arr;


       - (void)viewDidLoad
          {
            [super viewDidLoad];

             [self getData];
          }
```

Now is there some place that I need to do something with the managed objectcontext.. I am thinking I am just missing that one line of code somewhere..

Prerna

Comment: does your entity exist in your .xcdatamodel?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your `xcdatamodeld`. According to your code, it should be called `myapp.xcdatamodeld`. This model should contain the entity you want to fetch, in your case `Data`.

Comment: I have created the xcdatamodel and I am able to fetch and store data in a UIViewController but I wanted to display the stored data n the table and that is where I am not able to fetch the data. I had this problem earlier in the UI ViewController and it went away when I added     app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
where app is @property(nonatomic,retain) myappAppDelegate *app; once I added this in ViewDidLoad the error went away. So I am wondering if there is something similar that I need in TableViewControllers viewDidLoad that I need to add.

Comment: You should be using an instance of `NSFetchedResultsController`. Check out the docs and provided sample code.

Comment: I tried something like this in delegate.m didFinishlaunching method and I still get the same error..  MyTableViewController *tableviewcontroller;NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (!context) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    // Pass the managed object context to the view controller.
    tableviewcontroller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;